# While loop not working on name length validation (java)

Tags: java, while-loop

I wrote this program that asks for your Name, Last Name, Age and Grade and it will simply print everything out at the end.

I've added validation on the Age and Grade and it works well.

When i do the same thing for the Name field the code compiles without any error but for some reason the validation do not work; also, the program asks for another blank input. Why is this happening

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class student {
    static String name;
    static String lastName;
    static int age;
    static double grade;

    //constructor
    student(String aName, String aLastName, int anAge, double aGrade) {
    name = aName;
    lastName = aLastName;
    age = anAge;
    grade = aGrade;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    //create student
    student aStudent = new student(lastName, lastName, age, grade);

    //ask for name
    System.out.println("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");

    //Name length validation
    while (input.nextLine().length() < 1) {
        System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
    input.next();
    }


    //register name
    name = input.nextLine();

    //ask for last name
    System.out.println("Inserisci il tuo cognome: ");
    //register lastname
    lastName = input.nextLine();

    //ask for age
    System.out.println("Inserisci la tua eta: ");
    //age validation 
    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: ");
        input.next();
    }
    //register age
    age = input.nextInt();

    //ask for grade
    System.out.println("Inserisci il tuo voto: ");
    //grade validation
    while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: ");
        input.next();
    }
    //register grade
    grade = input.nextDouble();


    //Output finale
    System.out.println("Il tuo nome è: " + name +
        "\nIl tuo cognome è: " + lastName + 
        "\nLa tua eta è: " + age +
        "\nIl tuo voto è: " + grade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many problems in your code which you need to address:

1. You should always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the class should be `Student` instead of `student`. Although it does not have any impact on the execution of the program, not following the naming conventions makes your code look ugly.
2. You have instantiated `student` and stored the instance into `aStudent` even when you haven't asked the user for input. It should be done once the user has submitted the value of `firstName`, `lastName`, `age`, and `grade` of a student.

```
student aStudent = new student(lastName, lastName, age, grade);
```

Also, see how you have repeated `lastName`.

3. You should study about [the use of the static keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). None of the attributes of your class fits the requirement to be made a `static` attribute if you want to deal with instances of this class having individual values for each of the attributes. This particular program can still work with the `static` declaration but I strongly recommend you understand the concept of `static` clearly.
4. You need to store the input for name into a variable and compare the length so that you can loop back in case the input does not pass validation or carry on with the stored value otherwise.

```
String name = "";
// Name length validation
while ((name = input.nextLine()).length() < 2) {
    System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
}
```

5. Although there is no problem with your constructor, the way you have named its parameters is not common. The common style is to use the same name as the attributes and then use `this` with the attributes e.g. `this.name = name;`.
   Given below is the code incorporating these comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private double grade;

    // Constructor
    public Student(String name, String lastName, int age, double grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    // Create public getters and setters of the attributes

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask for name
        System.out.print("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");
        String name = "";
        // Name length validation
        while ((name = input.nextLine()).length() < 2) {
            System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
        }

        // Ask for last name
        System.out.print("Inserisci il tuo cognome: ");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();

        // Ask for age
        System.out.print("Inserisci la tua eta: ");
        // Age validation
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: ");
            input.next();
        }
        int age = input.nextInt();

        // Ask for grade
        System.out.print("Inserisci il tuo voto: ");
        // Grade validation
        while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: ");
            input.next();
        }
        double grade = input.nextDouble();

        Student student = new Student(name, lastName, age, grade);

        // Output finale
        System.out.println("Il tuo nome è: " + student.name + "\nIl tuo cognome è: " + student.lastName
                + "\nLa tua eta è: " + student.age + "\nIl tuo voto è: " + student.grade);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Inserisci il tuo nome: A
Error. Must be at least 2 char.
Arvind
Inserisci il tuo cognome: Avinash
Inserisci la tua eta: x
Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: 
???
Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: 
10
Inserisci il tuo voto: ?
Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: 
x
Attenzione! Devi inserire un numero: 
8.5
Il tuo nome è: Arvind
Il tuo cognome è: Avinash
La tua eta è: 10
Il tuo voto è: 8.5
```

Comment: (You may be interested to know that code blocks can be indented in list items within Markdown text using a double indent - use eight spaces instead of four. Similarly, if you wish to indent a fresh paragraph inside a list item, use two spaces).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 2 user inputs. You should create String variable and take input while that variable is less than 1 digit

```
String line = '';
while (line.length() < 1) {
    System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
line = input.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your solution, the program doesn't show any error in compiling. However, the error message shows up immediately with the input text. Also, the validation do not work

Answer (score 0):

It asks for the name twice, doesn't it? Once in the loop and once to set the variable. And the loop will accept a name with one character. To prevent this, use the <= operator. Also, classes should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. What do you suggest to avoid asking the input twice and therefore getting the name validation to work? Thank you

Comment: @Emiliano just save the name in the variable before the validation. Then check if the name is valid, if not(in while-loop body), you can just ask for the name again and save it int the variable again. Something like this should work:
 `name = input.nextLine();
 while(name.lenght() <= 1)
{
name = input.nextLine();
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
//ask for name
System.out.println("Inserisci il tuo nome: ");

//Name length validation
while (input.nextLine().length() < 1) {
    System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
input.next();
}

//register name
name = input.nextLine();
```

you are making some mistakes. Infact, inside the while loop condition you call `input.nextLine()`, so here the program take an input. After that, you call again `input.nextLine()`.

So what's the behaviour? The first time you type the name, it is read by the method you use as condition for the while loop. After that, you see the program asking for more input because of the `name = input.nextLine();` line.

**Little suggestion**: in Java is a good coding practice to call class with uppercase names, so in your case `Student`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you suggest to get the validation working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing a small mistake. In while loop, you are already reading input from console  using input.nextLine() which is not assigned to name variable.

```
while (input.nextLine().length() < 1) {
    System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
input.next();
}
```

The another blank input is asked because, you are calling input.next() again as below

```
  //register name
  name = input.next();
```

You can do something like this :

```
while ((name = input.nextLine()).length() < 2) {
    System.out.println("Error. Must be at least 2 char.");
}
```

Also, there was an issue with length comparison as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your solution I get the error "Cannot convert from int to String", therefore the program doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry.. It was a mistake with brackets.. Just corrected.. Please check now.